# Hero animation in SvelteKit

Tags: animation, sveltekit

I checked the docs and searched on google and I couldn't find any example or package that help me do an hero animation in sveltekit.

Hero animation is animation that morph tow components between tow transitions
For example, If I have a gallery page with images and when I click on an image it transition me to the image details page, I want the image to animate between the pages.
Flutter has an Hero widget that takes an id and animate pairs of hero widgets with the same id.
Does SvelteKit have something similar?, if not how cat I make my own?

**How can I have hero animation in sveltekit?**

Video example of hero animation
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWKENpwDKiM

Tried searching on google and checking sveltekit docs.
Expecting a link to a repo that I missed or an easy way to implement it myself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide links and screenshots to corresponding components as your description is difficult to understand.